# Can't add subscriber to group MailChimp API 3.0 C#

Tags: c#, restsharp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

When I want to add a subscriber to a interest, setting the boolean value to true, it remains false. I have no problems updating the merge-fields values using a similar request. When debugging I noticed one difference between the two and that is that the interests have a "key" and "value" in the request while the merge-fields do not:

[image]

The response concerning interests looks like this and it doesn't either have the "key" and "value".

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?

The relevant part of my updateMember function looks like this:

```
static void updateMember(){
    Dictionary<string, object> mergefieldsDic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    mergefieldsDic.Add("POSTCODE","4242");

    Dictionary<string, bool> interestDic = new Dictionary<object, bool>();
    interestDic.Add("cb0b422bf8", true);

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(new MemberRequest(mergefieldsDic, interestDic));

    IRestResponse<Member> response = client.Execute<Member>(request);

    foreach (var key in response.Data.merge_fields.Keys)
    {
        string value = response.Data.merge_fields[key].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
    foreach (var key in response.Data.interests.Keys)
    {
        string value = response.Data.interests[key].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

My MemberRequest class looks like this

```
public class MemberRequest
{
    public MemberRequest(){}
    public MemberRequest(Dictionary<string, object> merge_fields, Dictionary<object, bool> interests)
    {
        this.merge_fields = merge_fields;
        this.interests = interests;
    }
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,object> merge_fields { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<object, bool> interests { get; set; }
}
```

And my Member class looks like this

```
public class Member
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string email_address { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,object> merge_fields { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<object,bool> interests { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried to change the both interests dictionaries to `<bool,object>`,`\<string,bool>` and `<string,string>` but nothing worked.

I manage to get to it to work if I don't use the MemberRequest class and just do `request.AddBody(new { interests = new { cb0b422bf8 = true} });`

Comment: `When I want to add a subscriber to a interest it doesn't work` .... please explain what `it doesn't work` means. Did you get an error?

Comment: @ekad thank you for making me better at asking my question. I rephrased the question to say that the boolean value remains false even though I try to set it to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I did not get an error when I updated the member but when I tried to create a new member with the aforementioned classes I got a bad request from the API that the interests were an array and not an object as it has to be. To solve this I changed my interest `Dictionary<string,bool>`to `Dictionary<string,object>`.

Initially when I to changed the Dictionary I ended up having two nearly identical constructors and therefore my error was "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties".